# Flash GotoFrame on Keypress

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to figure out some code where when I press one of the 4 arrow keys, flash goes to a certain frame on the timeline. And when none of these keys are being pressed, it will return to its original start point on the timeline. I have seen some examples on this site, but I am struggling with it, especially returning to the original point on the timeline when there are no keypresses.

So for example :

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);

function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        gotoAndStop(40);
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        gotoAndStop(30);
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        gotoAndStop (10);
    }
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        gotoAndStop (20);
    }
}

stop();
```

I can get it to go to various points on the timeline, but I do not know how to make it return to its original point on the time line (keyframe 1) when none of those keyboard keys are being pressed.

What I am trying to do is to show on screen when a button is being pressed, and when its no longer being pressed to disapear

If anyone can help, I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: You can simply add another key (or button, ... ) to go to your original start point.

Comment: Thats the thing, I dont want to add another key. I just want to show when the key is being depressed, a graphic shows on screen. When its not being depressed, then the graphic goes away. But thanks anyway

Comment: I don't understand, you are talking about a button (pressed/released)  and keyboard keys on the stage ... please try to explain more the situation because it's unclear (at least for me) ...

Comment: Sorry about that. What I am trying to do is when a key is pressed, like the up key. It appears on screen as a graphic. When the key is released, the graphic disappears.

Comment: In that case, you've to listen to the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` event and "hide" that graphic ...

Answer (score 0):

Detect `KEY_DOWN` and `KEY_UP` events, if you want to return to the first frame when you release the keys, this could be a possible solution:

```
var frames:Object = {
    38: 10, // Up Key
    40: 20, // Down Key
    37: 40, // Left Key
    39: 30  // Right Key
};

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, showMessage);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, hideMessage);

function showMessage(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

        if(frames.hasOwnProperty(event.keyCode.toString())) gotoAndStop( frames[event.keyCode] );

}

function hideMessage(evt:KeyboardEvent):void{

        gotoAndStop( 1 );

}
```